# SevenSwitch UI background color in iOS 8

Tags: ios, swift

I am using the SevenSwitch control instead of the built in UISwitch. Instead of an on and off mode I want both sides to have the same background color.

I tried the following code:

```
let mySwitch = SevenSwitch()
let switchTintColor = UIColor(red: 109/255, green: 59/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1.0)
mySwitch.offLabel.backgroundColor = switchTintColor
mySwitch.onTintColor = switchTintColor
mySwitch.borderColor = switchTintColor
```

That gets really close to what I want except for the background behind the thumb view when the switch is off.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to set the `activeColor` and `inactiveColor` properties on the switch. That should get you what you're after.

```
mySwitch.activeColor = switchTintColor
mySwitch.inactiveColor = switchTintColor
```